# Moving a UIImageViews center point

Tags: ios, uiimageview, orientation, cgaffinetransform, cgpoint

I have a view which has two `UIImageViews`. The bottom holds an image which is a photo taken/selected by the user.

The top holds an image semi transparent with a transparent circle. The top `UIImageView` can be moved by a gesture pan.

When the VC `viewDidAppear` I calculate some ratios of the image and find the bottom image's new frame. I also find the center point of the top view that is moved.

With this center point I calculate where the center point would be on the original image size. When the device is then rotated, I re-calculate the sizes/ratios. I am now trying to update the top image views position on screen based on the new calculations. From my logs I see the values appear to be correct, but the view does not move as expected. No move occurs.

```
float newX = self.centerPointOnOriginalImage.x * self.scaleDownOriginalImageRatio;
float newY = self.centerPointOnOriginalImage.y * self.scaleDownOriginalImageRatio;
NSLog(@"The new center point for the photo mask view is: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(newX, newY)));
self.photoMaskView.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
// Find out how to move a view with transform here as the view is not moving as expected
NSLog(@"The view was moved to here: Center: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(self.photoMaskView.center));
```

Do I need to move the top `UIImageView` (`self.photoMaskView.center`) center point with a CGAffineTransform to actually make the view move, if so how do I do this?

Comment: Changing the `center` should be sufficient (no need to use a transform). Also, in `viewDidLoad` the views are not laid out yet, so the bounds/frame/center are not accurate. They are accurate in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillAppear` etc.

Comment: This is its own method, called with 'viewWillAppear' and 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation'. However, the Logs show the center point being updated but not actually moving on screen, remaining in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the move of the center point in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked.